# Passing JSON serialized data via hidden field

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, serialization, webforms

In ASP.NET WebForms I want to pass arbitrary data from server to client and back again. I am serializing to JSON and have been simply producing JavaScript that creates the object on the client. I have no problem sending data to the server with ajax, but there are situations where I also want to send a Javascript object data back to the server on postbacks. So I guess it needs to be in a hidden field.

A couple general questions about this.

1) What is the best way to do this in terms of minimizing complexity and optimizing space and efficiency? In researching this I discovered [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html) but there does not seem to be a good C# implementation. I did find one, but it was a couple years old and self-described as buggy so that scared me.

2) If I just pass a JSON string, how can I be sure it will be safe to include as the value for a hidden field? Is there any reason I might not want to do this? I could Base64 encode, but it seems like this adds a lot of overhead. What is considered the best or preferred method?

Comment: Why aren't you using session variables? (just curious)

Comment: How would I get that data from the client (in javascript)?

Comment: @Jamietre: Handlers and AJAX, the same way you're posting it back? (ashx/asmx)

Comment: Ajax is fine, and I *could* fire off an ajax call before a page got posted, I suppose, but if it's being posted anyway that seems an unnecessary trip to the server. And it's something else I would have to intercept.

Comment: @jamietre: I guess I need more insight in to the "original problem" before making a judgement call. I can recommend methods all day that contour to what you already have deemed suitable, but that doesn't help you solve the original problem at-hand.

Comment: Maybe i'm giving too much detail. I really just want suggestions on the best way to pass complex data from the client (Javascript) to the server on a POST, without a separate ajax call. Putting the data in a hidden field seems like a prerequisite, so what's the best way to encode it so it's safe, compact, and can be un-encoded by C# code on the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past, I've usually done the following:

1. Created a C# object that I can easily serialize to XML (.Net can do this natively and there are JSON serializers out there as well). (Actually I think .Net may do JSON as well... not sure though)
2. Take this object and share it with the client via a hidden field or lazy load it on the client via an AJAX request.
3. The client then parses and manipulates the XML (jQuery can do this) and sends it back to the server via AJAX or a hidden field via a POST.
4. Lastly I deserialize the XML (or JSON) from the client back into an Object and work with it from there.

So I'm not sure what you're trying to gain through encoding, but I think the expense of transforming the object from JSON (or XML) to something smaller  is too much overhead for any packaging/shrinking benefit. (Unless your a super high traffic site concerned more about bandwidth usage than server/client side processing.)

**EXAMPLE**

Hopefully this gives you an idea of how to accomplish this. Let me know if you have any more questions.

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <input type="button" id="btnObject" value="Show Object" /> 
    <input type="button" id="btnShowHid" value="Show Hidden Input Value" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="hidInput" value="" /> 
</body> 
</html> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js'></script> 
<script> 
    //Your JSON Object
    var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [ 
            {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"}, 
            {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"}, 
            {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"} 
        ] 
    }; 

    //jQuery Document Ready Event
    $(function(){
         //Get a reference to your hidden field
        var $hidInput = $("#hidInput");

        //Use json2.js library to convert the json object to a string
        //and assign it to the hidden input's value
        //NOTE: ASP.NET hidden input control reduces to a hidden input so you can treat them the same.
        $hidInput.val(JSON.stringify(myJSONObject));

        //Set up click events to view object and hidden value
        $("#btnShowHid").click(function(){
            alert($hidInput.val());
        });

        $("#btnObject").click(function(){
            alert(myJSONObject);
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is basically the architecture I am working with, do you have any suggestions on the actual implementation details for putting the data in a hidden field? E.g. just stick the JSON string right in there? Wouldn't this require some sort of further encoding to be safe, e.g. what about quotes? Any other chars that are ok in JSON but not a field? Or base64? Some other method? This doesn't have to be google.com efficient but I'd rather start with a good implementation rather than a bulky one, if there are any alternatives. Sort of what I was getting at with ProtocolBuffers but no C# impl.

Comment: You may want to avoid the whole issue of encoding by sending the json string to the client as a javascript variable.  ie. var x=<%=GetJsonString()%>;  Then stick the server-side representation in session state.  This gives you the best of both worlds.  No chance of tampering with the form post, and no need to encode the JSON.

Comment: Isn't JSON.stringify going to return something with double-quotes? I don't think that will work for the value of a hidden field. This is really my concern.

Comment: @jamietre, Yes but they appear to be escaped double-quotes. If you try my example above, you'll find that it successfully assigns the result of JSON.stringify to a hidden field without any problems. If you view the DOM in firebug (firefox browser) you'll also be able to see the actual value of the hidden field which contains double-quotes without any problems.