# ViewState lost between consecutive partial postbacks?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, viewstate

**Background:**

I have a page where I have various client-side events being handled with JavaScript. I want to "sync" some of these events with server-side events, or otherwise call functions from the code-behind.

Some of the functions I want to call with JavaScript may make changes to controls (e.g. changing a textbox value) in a form I have on the page. They may also change some values I have stored in the ViewState, as I want some values to persist through postbacks. I do not want to a full postback, and have the controls that may be changed in an update panel.

I am currently "calling" functions in my code-behind with JavaScript by clicking invisible buttons that trigger partial postback on my page through an asynchronous postback trigger in my update panel.

**Problem:**

One of my client-side events calls a JavaScript function that clicks more than one of the invisible buttons (client-side stuff happens between the clicks that may affect how the the code-behind functions behave). When I have the JavaScript clicking more than one button, the changes made to the ViewState do not seem to persist, and only the changes from the last click are observed.

**Example:**

I might not have explained this very well, so here is a simplified version of what I have (which I can reproduce the issue with).

*Markup:*

```
<asp:Button ID="btnA" runat="server" style="display: none;" />
<asp:Button ID="btnB" runat="server" style="display: none;" />
<div style="background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px;" onclick="AB();"></div>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upForm" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnA" EventName="Click" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnB" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function AB() {
    $('#<%= btnA.ClientID %>').click();
    $('#<%= btnB.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

*Code-behind:*

```
Protected Sub btnA_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnA.Click
    ViewState("AB") += "A"
End Sub
Protected Sub btnB_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnB.Click
    ViewState("AB") += "B"
End Sub
```

**Questions:**

1. Why are the changes to ViewState between partial postbacks lost?
2. How can I save the changes between the partial postbacks? Session variables work great, but I would rather not have to resort to using them. I also cannot save the values in an invisible control as I am actually changing a serialized object in the ViewState.
3. Is there perhaps a better way I could be doing this that would work?

Comment: I know this is obvious, but did you make sure that in your .aspx EnableViewState is set to true?

Comment: You're sending out two requests, A and B, at the same time. A is sent and, before it returns, you send B. That means the updated ViewState returned from A has not been returned and so B still has the 'old' ViewState

Comment: @Joe, yes I have set EnableViewState="true" for the whole page
@grahammendick, I was thinking that might be what`s happening, although I`m not sure exactly how it works. Is it an issue of time? I set breakpoints in both my browser and Visual Studio and have tried it with significant time between each event and it still happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get it working for my case, but I think some of the options other users have suggested could have worked for me as well. Since my case seems pretty unique (partly because it's a hack method), I've included some other suggestions in this answer for future reference.

1. Since the JavaScript is simulating two buttons being clicked, two consecutive partial postbacks are made. The second request is fired before the first one is returned, and so the second server event grabs the old ViewState rather than the updated one from the first event.

   - Thanks to [graham mendick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085096/viewstate-lost-between-consecutive-partial-postbacks#comment14513299_11085096) and [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11086556/1405830) for pointing this out.
2. Since my client and server events did not have to be perfectly in sync (it only needs to *appear* in sync to the user), I reorganized the code behind functions so that only one partial postback was needed per client event, while still keeping the logical flow of events. To be clear, this is more a workaround than a real solution.

   - [Crab Bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085419/1405830) suggested serializing a JSON object into a hidden form field. While not exactly what I'm looking for, I think it's worth mentioning in case others stumble across a similar issue. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173292/passing-json-serialized-data-via-hidden-field).
3. [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11086556/1405830) recommended using page methods, which I've taken a (brief) look at and it seems like it might work. To move away from update panels for me at this point and put the page back together again with his suggestions though would take quite a bit of work due to what's already on the page. I might come back to this in the future though and try it out (or maybe use it for something else). Some more details on [using jQuery to call page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) and [consume web services](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).

Answer (score 2):

I tested this out and view state does get updated on partial requests.
There could be a problem with 2 consecutive partial requests. the first request would have to return before the second one fires for it to work.

The way viewstate works is there is a hidden field called __VIEWSTATE that gets posted on every request. ASP.NET uses this data to maintain any state it needs.
So if the first request hasn't returned to the browser and the view state has not been updated at the browser it will not be sent in the second request.

An update panel response looks something like this:

```
248|updatePanel|ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_up|
.......
__VIEWSTATE|/wEPDwUKLTM1OTc4......
```

The viewstate is then updated on client side.
I would check that it is beeing updated before the second request.

That being said I think using update panels is a bit outdated. if i were you i would use javascript and webmetods. take a look at [this](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).  of course it would depend on the exact scenario. in my opinion the method you are using is dirty and unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe you're right about how the second request is getting an outdated ViewState. And yes, what I'm doing now is definitely a hack. At this point I think I'll stick with update panels for this website though and see if I can come back and try page methods if I get a chance later. The link is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that if you are 'pressing' two buttons with Javascript and the page postsback - then only one of the server side event handlers will register so you will only get one of your click events will fire.

I guess the design of the page model is built around human interactions - and humans will only click one button hence only one server side click event will be capable of being fired. Your method while very cunning - essentially has subverted the page model (with 2 button presses) so the model stops behaving.

Just off the top of my head though - but makes sense to me.

When I have needed to have JavaScript events persisting in a ViewState type of way - I have rolled my own persistance method e.g.

1. Put a hidden field on the form
2. When the JavaScript fires then JSON serialise the control state you want to persist (or object) in a object structure that makes sense to you
3. When the page reloads then using JavaScript (or JQuery etc..) to pick out the persisted JSON string. Turn it back to an object (using JSON parser or eval if you like) then use that to reset the page state.

If you use the [pageLoad()](http://encosia.com/document-ready-and-pageload-are-not-the-same/) javaScript method then this will fire for both a full and partial postback which might be useful for your situation.

Just my experience. Maybe relevant/helpful to you

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, I can verify that both server events are firing and successfully modifying the ViewState. Debugging it with Visual Studio shows ViewState("AB")="A" after btnA_Click and ViewState("AB")="B" after btnB_Click (the desired behavior is ViewState("AB")="AB" here).

Comment: What happens without the update panels - does it work then? Could it be that because the ViewState is stashed in a hidden field outside of the update panel - then the ViewState isn't been persisted properly. That said an update panel must interact with the ViewState to persist in it's own controls. What happens if you update a hidden field with runat="server" within the update panel instead of using the StateBag (ViewState[])? Does that work?

Comment: Without update panels I get a full postback and only the first event fires. Storing the value in a hidden field within the update panel gives the same behavior as with the ViewState. Your updated answer does not exactly fit my needs as I need to be able to grab the object from the server and I'm not easily able to serialize it to XML or JSON (although I could). However, it does give me an idea on something else I could try that may possibly work. Thanks again for your feedback!